# Add username to Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, account

I ran "rails g migration add_username_to_users username:string" and "rake db:migrate" and added this to my application_controller

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
protected
def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
 end
```

but I get this error when I try to load a devise view 
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#new
undefined method `for' for # Did you mean? fork
Extracted source (around line #7)

Line 7 is:
    `devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }`

**UPDATE**

now I am receiving a different error

NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new

```
 <%= f.username_field :username, :autofocus => true, autocomplete: "username" %>
```

**Update 2**
Now the sign up page loads but when I press the sign up button I get this error
LoadError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext

```
 load_dependency(file) { result = super }
```

Comment: How is your entire form like? And Show more details about your routes.rb file, plz.

Answer (score 1):

Try to the following

On `application_controller.rb`

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
protected
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation])

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me])

  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password])
end
```

This now permit your extra column keys like `username` for more click [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters)

Now, `devise` by default use `bcrypt` for password encryption, you need to install `bcrypt` for password encryption option like below

```
gem install bcrypt
OR
gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby
```

Hope to help

Answer (score 0):

Your usage is wrong, this the right way`devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:subscribe_newsletter])`. This the docs https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Comment: Thanks, that fixed that error but Now im receiving another error, ill post it now

Comment: @Pagaley12 ` f.username_field` I guess this is wrong and try to change it to ` f.text_field, : username `

Comment: that made the page load but I cant sign up, I get an error when I rpess the button

Comment: @Pagaley12 You should install the gem bcrypt